# Is there a way to give a user limited, non-admin account access in cPanel?

Tags: user-accounts, cpanel, limited-access

I have a dedicated virtual server with two domains domainA/domainB on it.  Each domain has its own cPanel account. I want to give someone access to very specific items ("metrics" items, ie: Webalizer, AWStats, etc) on each cPanel.

The user already has a standard email/FTP account on one of the two domains. But I can't find a way to assign that user access to additional features.

In WHM I can “Add A New Account” - create the username, add the “Feature List” and then select domainA and I get an error saying domainA is already assigned to an account. This makes me think this is creating "Admins" for new domains...But not how to add a limited user to an existing domain.

Is there some magic that I am missing here?

Comment: I fear what I am looking for is not possible in cPanel.  I hope I am wrong and am simply just looking in the right place.  Can anyone confirm this: https://features.cpanel.net/topic/multiple-cpanel-logins-cpanel-subusers

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately cPanel does not support sub-accounts, or other permission management in the way you're looking for. Every cPanel account has just one login, which grants full access to the account.

The [feature request you linked to](https://features.cpanel.net/topic/multiple-cpanel-logins-cpanel-subusers) is real, and unfortunately it does appear to be shelved.